# creating an enum/final class in java

Tags: java, enums, global-variables, final, static-variables

I'm trying to figure out the best way to create a class whose sole purpose is to be a container for global static variables. Here's some pseudocode for a simple example of what I mean...

```
public class Symbols {
   public static final String ALPHA = "alpha";
   public static final String BETA = "beta";

   /* ...and so on for a bunch of these */
}
```

I don't need constructors or methods. I just need to be able to access these "symbols" from everywhere simply by calling: `Symbols.ALPHA;`

I **DO need** the actual value of the String, so I can't use an enum type. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: RE: 'I do need the actual value of the String, so I can't use an enum type.' - You can still get String values from enum types...

Comment: @Nate... mind giving me a small example? my enum skills are rusty.

Comment: Jon Skeet posted mostly what I'm talking about - in addition you can override the enum's 'toString()' method to return the enum's "value" instead of the enum's "name" if you wanted a tradeoff between type-safety and ease of casting to a String.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, it's not clear what else you need beyond the code you've already given - other than maybe making the class final and giving it a private constructor.

However, in order to avoid accidentally using an inappropriate value, I suspect you *would* be better off making this an enum, like this:

```
public enum Symbol {
   ALPHA("alpha"),
   BETA("beta");

   private final String value;

   private Symbol(String value) {
     this.value = value;
   }

   public String getValue() {
     return value;
   }
}
```

That way:

- You can't accidentally use `Symbol.ALPHA` where you're really just expecting a string
- You can't accidentally use a string where you're really expecting a symbol
- You can still easily get the string value associated with a symbol
- You can switch on the different symbol values if you need to

Comment: I was thinking about this approach, but you'd have to call the `getValue()` method to get the actual value, right?

Comment: btw Jon... I might have not been clear about this, but I specifically need the String value.

Comment: @Hristo: Yes, which you can get via `getValue()`. Given the benefits listed, is calling `getValue()` really so awful?

Comment: @Jon... haha, that's not my decision to make. If I were calling the shots, I'd do it this way :) The reason I asked this question is to figure out different ways to do this, weigh the pros/cons, and present the options to the person that will give me the thumbs-up for implementation.

Comment: @Hristo: Then what you've got, but making the class final and adding a private constructor is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using an interface. No need to construct, values are public, static and final, and can obviously be strings. Such an interface would look similar to your class:

```
public interface Symbols {
  public static final String ALPHA = "alpha";
  public static final String BETA = "beta";
  /* and so on */
}
```

You can access the fields directly from everywhere in your code (given it's public) as `Symbols.ALPHA` etc.

Or, you can use an enum even though you want strings - `ALPHA.toString()` will return "ALPHA" (and if you want a slightly different string, you can override `toString()`)

Comment: would an external class need to implement this interface then?

Comment: No, there's no need to implement it. It would just be a "constant holder", just like you're looking for.

Comment: @Hristo - no, it can access them using the interface name - `Symbols.ALPHA`.

Comment: hmm... I think that's what I'm looking for. Jon Skeet brings up some good points below. Any thoughts on pros/cons vs his suggestion?

Comment: @eran... mind posting a small code example of such an interface?

Comment: @Hristo, I've updated the answer with an example of such an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Are these configuration parameters or simply "constants" which don't change no matter what? For the former, I'd rather create a configuration class and instantiate it with different values for each environment. Then simply use dependency injection to inject these configurations in different classes. If your requirement is the latter or you are not using DI (Spring/Guice), static classes/interfaces are good to go.

Comment: These would fall under the constants category, but this list will be ever-growing.